# Unable to DATE_SUB correctly in a double inner join

Tags: mysql, datetime, inner-join

I'm writing a query to update some chained rowsthat looks like this

```
SELECT T.Id, 
T.Id + 1 AS NewID, 
T.DifferenceTime, 
RAT.AllowedDate, 
RAT.ExpirationDate, 
DATE_SUB(RAT.AllowedDate, INTERVAL T.DifferenceTime MINUTE) AS NewAllowedDate, 
DATE_SUB(RAT.ExpirationDate, INTERVAL T.DifferenceTime MINUTE) AS NewExpiringDate
FROM ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS RAT 
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT T2.*,
 ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,T2.ExpirationDate,UTC_TIMESTAMP())) AS DifferenceTime 
 FROM ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS RAT
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS 
    WHERE Expired = 0 AND ExpirationDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP()
 ) AS T2 ON T2.IdRoom = RAT.IdRoom AND T2.ChainId = RAT.ChainId
 WHERE RAT.IdRoom = 1 
 AND RAT.AccessToken = '5092FFA0B3721AE5EC757649DE983F8020220104215810' 
 AND RAT.RefId = 'B49F723F2FE0FD38063DA26F3EAEDBED' 
 AND RAT.KeyCode = '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm' 
 AND RAT.ExpirationDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP()
 AND RAT.Expired = 0
) AS T ON T.IdRoom = RAT.IdRoom 
AND T.ChainId = RAT.ChainId 
AND T.AccessToken = RAT.AccessToken 
AND T.RefId = RAT.RefId 
AND T.AllowedDate = RAT.AllowedDate
```

This suppose to select a row by IdRoom, AccessToken, RefId, KeyCode and be above a certain date and not Expired.
Then get all chainded rows by ChainId and calculate time different between UTC_TIMESTAMP() and row ExpirationDate. (I guess it works till this point)
With that difference in minute, I want to calculate new datetimes but it doesn't work.

I've attached a screenshot with results
[image]

As you can see, it looks like NewAllowedDate and NewExpiringDate get calculated only for the first row.. But NewID gets calculated for all of them..

I can't understand where my query is wrong.
Any ideas?

Here the table and some data insert example

```
CREATE TABLE `ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS` (   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `IdRoom` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   `AccessToken` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `RefId` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `KeyCode` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,   `Allowed` int(1) NOT NULL,   `Used` int(1) NOT NULL,   `Expired` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `ChainId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',   `StartDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `AllowedDate` datetime NOT NULL,   `ExpirationDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   `ResidenceTime` int(5) NOT NULL,   `Url` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS` (`Id`, `IdRoom`, `AccessToken`, `RefId`, `KeyCode`, `Allowed`, `Used`, `Expired`, `ChainId`, `StartDate`, `AllowedDate`, `ExpirationDate`, `ResidenceTime`, `Url`) VALUES (1, 1, '5092FFA0B3721AE5EC757649DE983F8020220104215810', 'B49F723F2FE0FD38063DA26F3EAEDBED', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 1, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-04 23:30:46', 60, '/it'), (2, 1, '9CAB5CABB559260D41366E1041B46D0320220104233046', 'B086A4B3F4996C69B4DBB206C2E0D799', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-04 23:31:46', '2022-01-05 00:31:46', 60, '/it'), (3, 1, '3A2AE9CAC195B9938D25AE654790FAE020220104233046', 'E756AF83048259114F7E0BA04FFA799E', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-05 00:32:46', '2022-01-05 01:32:46', 60, '/it'), (4, 1, '17267FAC80875252F5F1E2585D078B1D20220104233046', '62143086CF25D276FD4C6D4465BDD41E', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-05 01:33:46', '2022-01-05 02:33:46', 60, '/it'), (5, 1, '39F47036B85694A231668BB8DFBF3CD120220104233046', 'C2C8F545B9FF7C59D50958C14EE61BF7', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-05 02:34:46', '2022-01-05 03:34:46', 60, '/it'), (6, 1, '61919A70C0D7AD4FB642BE1A3D6FE10420220104233046', 'EB1F2AF642C779B29F89023260A3AC94', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-05 03:35:46', '2022-01-05 04:35:46', 60, '/it'), (7, 1, '62BCFCCAC7F2EAFD5B1E06B32A810C1420220104233046', 'DDFB911F2197B50861AABD77005D9946', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-05 04:36:46', '2022-01-05 05:36:46', 60, '/it'), (8, 1, '6F72CCB6F3DF8F90C1A2911A7F1E097720220104233046', 'CCD116F4D4EFA9AE7D9B8DA780C5A73E', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-05 05:37:46', '2022-01-05 06:37:46', 60, '/it'), (9, 1, 'E8610F5C7551DA2695360B77431BBB1020220104233046', '49ABCCBDF6FC02FF290357B6A29DB2FC', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 1, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-05 06:38:46', '2022-01-05 07:38:46', 60, '/it'), (10, 1, '78BFEAF3EC52298B9EB5CDA8920168FE20220104233046', '755E481F29003C1EDC3A682D5037EF9F', '2773217uysagkasd8wqejhjkasdsm', 0, 0, 0, 1, '2022-01-04 22:30:46', '2022-01-05 07:39:46', '2022-01-05 08:39:46', 60, '/it');


ALTER TABLE `ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS`   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),   ADD KEY `IX_ACCESS_TOKEN` (`AccessToken`),   ADD KEY `KeyCode` (`KeyCode`),   ADD KEY `RefId` (`RefId`),   ADD KEY `IdRoom` (`IdRoom`),   ADD KEY `Allowed` (`Allowed`),   ADD KEY `Used` (`Used`),   ADD KEY `Expired` (`Expired`);

ALTER TABLE `ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS`   MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```

Comment: could you edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS;` and some inserts for sample data and desired and actual results for that sample data that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: You're right: I've added the table structure and some inserts. What is the point to show output as text in this case?

Comment: Even with this simple query something is not working 

SELECT
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,RAT.ExpirationDate,UTC_TIMESTAMP()) AS T,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),RAT.ExpirationDate) AS T2,
RAT.AllowedDate,
RAT.AllowedDate - INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),RAT.ExpirationDate) MINUTE AS NewAllowedDate,
DATE_SUB(RAT.AllowedDate, INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),RAT.ExpirationDate) MINUTE) AS NewAllowedDate2
FROM ROOMS_ACCESS_TOKENS RAT

Comment: I believe you may have stumbled on a MySQL bug where first row repeats for all rows of the `DATE_SUB` calculation. See this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c0727695958afc0cde0f60dbf47dc10). Interestingly, *every* other interval works including `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `WEEK`, `DAY`, `HOUR`, even `SECOND` but ***not*** `MINUTE`. Moreover, `DATEADD` works but reproduces your issue using negative minutes: `-1 * T.DIFFERENCE`!

Comment: To me, it looks like it's working exactly as the query is designed. The calculations of the new dates are correct but only within the context of each row. Were you expecting them to be cumulative somehow? Can you describe what you were expecting?

Comment: Please wrap those SQL lines.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.

Answer (score 0):

These sound redundant.  The former one is dynamic; the latter one is potentially not-yet-set.

```
AND RAT.ExpirationDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP()
AND RAT.Expired = 0
```

I do not understand your date arithmetic, especially since the columns, being DATETIME, have 'second' resolution, yet the arithmetic involved 'MINUTEs'.

What is the meaning of "ABS" in  `ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,T2.ExpirationDate, UTC_TIMESTAMP())) AS DifferenceTime`

Please do not use the same alias twice; it confuses me, and maybe the parser.  (I am thinking of `RAT`, at least.)